# No message on exit 1?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sqlplus, oracle19c

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
export DATABASE=U414_157_6300/U414_157_6300@db1230cn:1526/DBG192
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
export JAVA_HOME=/u01/app/java/jdk180_231
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/client19
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/client19/lib
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH

echo "exit" |sqlplus -L $DATABASE | grep 'Connected' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Database is up and the connection is successful!!"
        exit 0;
else
        echo "Database seems to be down!!"
        exit 1;
fi
```

This script is to check if the DB is up or down. When up I get the below result.

```
./db_status.sh
Database is up and the connection is successful!!
```

But when DB is down I am getting nothing!! why??

```
./db_status.sh
[root@qaapp828cn u414_157_6300]#
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Connected` message you're looking for is written to stdout?

Comment: BTW, `if sqlplus -L "$DATABASE" <<<"exit" 2>&1 | grep -q Connected; then` might be an easier way to write that. And I'd _hope_ that sqlplus would be a well-behaved-enough program to have a nonzero exit status if it couldn't connect to the database server, though that may not be the case -- I wrote my own database client back when I was at an Oracle shop specifically because sqlplus was so poorly-thought-out with regard to scriptability. (That's something like 15 years ago now, so I certainly don't remember the details of the specific complaints that led to that action).

Comment: btw, re: `set -e`, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: Be aware, that the script will wait, till the sqlplus command ends. Or in other words, if the `sqlplus` command does not end, your script will not end. There is no timeout !

Comment: @Marco, ...since its stdin will be at EOF after it's read `exit`, though, it's reasonable to expect it to exit. I would expect it to exit just with a `</dev/null` and no `echo "exit" |`, for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have `set -e` at the beginning of the script. That makes the script exit immediately if any command has a non-zero exit code. So when `grep` fails, the script exits immediately and you never test `$?` on the next line.

But there are exceptions: If the command is used as the test in an `if`, the script doesn't exit. So instead of testing `$?`, just test the command itself.

```
if echo "exit" |sqlplus -L $DATABASE | grep -q 'Connected'
then
        echo "Database is up and the connection is successful!!"
        exit 0;
else
        echo "Database seems to be down!!"
        exit 1;
fi
```